# Echo json encoded string in symfony twig

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig

I trying to echo json encode string in twig. This is my code,

Controller

```
$jsonArray = array(
            array(
                'label' => 'CN Clogs Beach',
                'data' => 5
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'Prod my prod',
                'data' => 5
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'New Pro',
                'data' => 3
            )
        );

        $jsonArray = json_encode($jsonArray);

        return $this->render("EagleAdminBundle:dashboard:index.html.twig", array(                        
                    'jsonArray' => $jsonArray
        ));
```

This is twig file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = {{ jsonArray }};
</script>
```

Instead of getting json array I get something like this,

```
var data = [{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;CN Clogs Beach&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:5},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Prod my prod&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:5},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;New Pro&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:3}];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = {{ jsonArray | raw }};
</script>
```

or

```
var data = $.parseJSON('{{ jsonArray | raw }}');
```